# Problem with nsurlconnection timeout

Tags: iphone, timeout, nsurlconnection

I've got a wierd problem with NSURLConnection. I've set the connection time out of 20 seconds like this.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];
NSURLConnection *con= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I'm implementing the delegate methods for the NSURLConnection as well.

Now when I ran the app, the connection did not time out after 20 seconds but after 2-3 minutes it gave error for 'No internet connection'. Isn't it supposed to  give a timeout error after 20 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion for timeoutInterval says that it starts (is set to 0) when a process of load activity occurs:

> The timeout interval specifies the
>   limit on the idle
>       interval alloted to a request in the process of loading. The "idle
>       interval" is defined as the period of time that has passed since the
>       last instance of load activity occurred for a request that is in the
>       process of loading. Hence, when an instance of load activity occurs
>       (e.g. bytes are received from the network for a request), the idle
>       interval for a request is reset to 0. If the idle interval ever
>       becomes greater than or equal to the timeout interval, the request
>       is considered to have timed out. This timeout interval is measured
>       in seconds.

No internet connection is an error. So probably the timeout will actually occur in 20 seconds (set time) if it gets a connection but takes more time to load...

Comment: May be. But the discussions in [here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/25282) also suggest that timeoutInterval is 240 seconds minimum for iphone if connection request has a body. So no matter what, it will atleast take 240 seconds if there's a body unless I cancel the connection after 20 seconds.

Comment: user430338's find is important if you are sending a synchronous(blocking) request and need it to time out sooner...